# no package manager found when deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Today i have an error when trying to deplyo my amplify app

It says:

> ✖ There was an error initializing your environment.
> 2023-03-15T15:49:07.075Z [INFO]:  No package manager found.
> 2023-03-15T15:49:07.075Z [INFO]: Resolution: Install npm or yarn to
> compile overrides for this project.

I have no idea where this came from. I try to re-deploy an working version but i get exact the same error.

This only happens during deployment when i do `git push`

When i do `amplify push` it works fine.

Does somebody experience this same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with aws-amplify/cli version 11.0.0

I paginated back to the version that worked, and it used version 10.8.1

Now i updated my `amplify.yml` file:

```
build:
  commands:
    - npm uninstall @aws-amplify/cli
    - npm install @aws-amplify/cli@10.8.1
    - amplifyPush --simple
```

After unintall the current amplify/cli version and installing an older one that worked, it deploys now without errors!

Comment: For reference there's a bug raised on github: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/12221
There's a comment that it's to do "With the release of Amplify CLI version v11, AWS CDK v2 has been released. If your Amplify project utilizes overrides or custom resources created on a prior version of the Amplify CLI the resources will need to be migrated to the new version."

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this;

Build settings ->Build image settings-> Edit->Live package updates:

Amplify CLI: `10.5.3-circular-dep-fix.0`